# trying to merge 2 GeoDataFrames with sjoin and ran for infinity

Tags: python, geospatial, geopandas

I have 2 geopandas dataframe

gdfTraffic_df - contains polygon in geometry column
num of rows = 1,916,560

[image]

gdfAlerts_df - contains point in geometry column
num of rows = 632,259

[image]

im trying to merge the 2 geodataframe to a new df that give me the rows only with the polygon that contains point
i execute this code

```
merged = gdfTraffic_df.sjoin(gdf, predicate="contains")
```

unfortunately it looks like its never stop runing

```py
merged = gdfTraffic_df.sjoin(gdf, predicate="contains")
```

expected to get new df that contains df with polygon and the points he contains

Comment: Just read your question title again - are you getting an error or is it just taking a long time? If you’re getting an error please post the full traceback in your question. A long runtime is not an error.

Comment: Also [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)- instead, copy the result of `print(df)` into your question as a code block. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it for anyone who will meet it in future
i devied it to weeks and did the action on small group of dates and it worked !
thanx

Comment: Congratz on solving this! Please add more detail to your answer so future readers can easily know what they need to do if they have the same question as yours :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have either Pygeos version >= 0.8 installed or you have shapely version >= 2.0. These are [optional dependencies](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html#using-the-optional-pygeos-dependency) which dramatically improve performance for large operations like this.

```bash
# conda
conda install pygeos --channel conda-forge
# pip
pip install pygeos
```

If you are thinking about installing them, I’d give the [optional dependencies](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html#using-the-optional-pygeos-dependency)  installation guide a read to make sure this advice is still up to date, and to check the list of known downsides, as there is at least one thing that won’t work with the pygeos speed up (CRS transforms for 3D objects).

If you have both of these, you can check that pygeos is enabled with:

```py
geopandas.options.use_pygeos  # should be True
```

If it is and it’s still taking a long time, then I’d go make some cookies or something. It’s a large operation you have there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur respone . do u mean i should work with pygeos instead of geopandas ? when im trying to install the pygeos and continue with the code in the post its seems to not recognize the geopandas at all

Comment: no - I mean you should follow the geopandas docs and install pygeos in addition - it's an optional dependency used by geopandas to speed up/vectorize operations. If you're using something interactive like a jupyter notebook you're going to have to restart your kernel after completing the installation.

Comment: is this can work in google colab ?

Comment: Yep it should. I don’t work with colab though.